# How could macOS installer act as both an installer package "InstallAssistant.pkg" and a disk image "SharedSupport.dmg"?

Tags: install, dmg

Apple has been providing single file macOS installer package "InstallAssistant.pkg" since Big Sur, this package install the app to "/Applications/Install macOS Ventura.app", and copy itself to "/Applications/Install macOS Ventura.app/Contents/SharedSupport/SharedSupport.dmg" using /bin/cp command.

My Question is, How could this file act as both an installer package and a disk image?

You can get the installer url from flowing page:

https://mrmacintosh.com/macos-ventura-13-full-installer-database-download-directly-from-apple/

Comment: A .pkg file (also an .app file) is, for all intents and purposes, nothing more than a special purpose folder. As it is a folder it can contain pretty much anything, including disk image (.dmg) files.

Comment: But "InstallAssistant.pkg" is a single file can be downloaded using browser.